# How to iterate through controls array property from Forms in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, index-signature

I have the following problem I need to iterate through the controls property of a Form in Angular using a forEach loop. I am writing the following code:

```
const arr = this.bankForm.controls;
arr.forEach((element: {[key: string]: AbstractControl}) => {

});
```

And I have the next error:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way you could iterate through the controls

**Solution**

```
Object.keys(this.bankForm.controls).forEach((control: string) => {
    const typedControl: AbstractControl = this.bankForm.controls[control];
    console.log(typedControl) 
    // should log the form controls value and be typed correctly
});
```

This is because the `Object.keys();`returns an array of the the key values which you can then iterate over using the the `forEach();` array method.

**Documentation**

[forEach() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). /
[Object.keys method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). /
[Angular Form Controls](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

**Edit**

control will always be a string coming from the `forEach();`, so what I would do is try declaring something new below of the correct type. See above. That makes my IDE recognise it's a form control so will hopefully meet your tsconfig.